# The set of function that can be written as $f(x,y)=g(x+h(y))$ is meagre on $\mathcal C$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

I want to show that the set of two-variable functions that can be written as $f(x,y)=g(x+h(y))$ is meagre on $\mathcal C$; we know that $g$ is a strictly increasing function.

The problem sounds easy and I've thought of two approaches:

The first approach is to show that $f$ is partially differentiable at one point. $$f_x=\frac{\partial g(x+h(y))}{\partial (x+h(y))}\frac{\partial (x+h(y))}{\partial x}.$$

Obviously, since $g$ is increasing, $f_x$ must exists for at least one point.

The second approach is kind of informal. First, from the set $\mathcal C$, I remove all the "repeated functions" $f'$, if $f'=\phi(f)$ for some increasing $\phi$ and $f$ is already an element of $\mathcal C$, then we remove $f'$, generating a new set called $C'$. I also make sure that the set of functions $"x+h(y)"$ is a subset of $C'$. Then I try to show that the set of functions $x+h(y)$ is meagre on $C'$; this is easy because $x+h(y)$ always have partial derivative.

Could you please help me with two questions?

1. How to formally construct the set $C'$?
2. In both approaches, I use the argument that the set of functions that are partially-differentiable at at least one point, is a meagre set of the set of continuous functions; I am not sure if this is correct, or if there are better way around to prove my ideas.